# Using DistributedDataParallel with modelParallel

Tags: pytorch

I have a model that won't fit on a single GPU.

I am mapping it to gpus using

```
part_one_of_model.to("cuda:0")
part_one_of_model.to("cuda:1")
```

No I want to use DistributedDataParallel.

When using distributeddataparallel it tells you to map the model to the GPU using.

```
model.to(rank)
```

However I want every rank to have access to two GPUs and I want to know how to map the first part of my model to the first GPU belonging to that rank and the second part to the second GPU.

Is this possible?